# audited, Look up audits belonging to a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, acts-as-audited

I am using [`audited`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) to track changes for a model called `Page`.  I would like to be able to find all audits associated with a certain user (via `user_id` in the audits table).

How can I do that?  So far, the only way I have found to access the `Audit` model is like this:

```
@audits = Audited::Adapters::ActiveRecord::Audit.all
```

Which just doesn't seem like it's the right way to do things.

Trying `@audits = Audit.all` gives an `Uninitialized constant` error.

Is there a more graceful way of interacting with models provided by gems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like

`include Audited::Adapters::ActiveRecord::Audit`

and then you can do

`@audits = Audit.all`

?

I think that should work... Or better yet:

`include Audited`

Comment: Yes this works include Audited, see a simple example:
class Audit < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Audited
end

Comment: it's worth noting that you can do Audited.audit_class which then allows you to do things like Audited.audit_class.where("...")

Answer (score 3):

You can access all Audit records with

```
Audited::Audit.all
```

I got the result when I typed the

```
Audited.audit_class
```

> DEPRECATION WARNING: audit_class is deprecated and will be removed
>   from Rails 5.0 (Audited.audit_class is now always Audited::Audit. This
>   method will be removed.).

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an efficient way to do so, but this is how I do it.

In a Rails console I retrieve a record which I know is audited.

`@page = Page.first`

I then retrieve that record's first audit.

`@audit = @page.audits.first`

You can then call `#class` on `@audit`

`@audit.class`

Result:

```
Audited::Adapters::ActiveRecord::Audit(id: integer, created_at: 
datetime, updated_at: datetime, auditable_id: integer, auditable_type: 
string, user_id: integer, user_type: string, username: string, action: 
string, audited_changes: text, version: integer, comment: string, 
full_model: text, remote_address: string, associated_id: integer, 
associated_type: string, request_uuid: string)
```

`Audited::Adapters::ActiveRecord::Audit` is the class name, which you can then use in your search.

`audits = Audited::Adapters::ActiveRecord::Audit.where(:user_id => 8675309)`